# Relative HTML Image Reference (LAMP)

Tags: html, image, relative-path, src

Really new to web development, but I can't work out why my relative image reference isn't working. I have my index.php in DocumentRoot [/var/www/vhosts/project0/html/], with a separate folder where I have put my images [/var/www/vhosts/project0/images/]. I have looked at the permissions, and they seem to be ok; see ls -l output at [/var/www/vhosts/project0/] below:

- drwxr-xr-x 2 aiden aiden 4096 Mar 12 18:48 html
- drwxr-xr-x 2 aiden aiden 4096 Feb 14 12:12 images

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>My Lecture Reader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CSCI S-75</h1>
    <ul>
      <img src="P001.jpg"/> <br> <!-- Works -->
      <img src="../images/P001.jpg"/> <br> <!-- Doesn't Work -->
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: I have copied P001.jpg from images/ to html/ for debugging.

I am running Xbuntu on a VirtualBox, with Apache2 as web server.

If you can help, or point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful.

Cheers,

Aiden

EXTRA DETAIL:

project0.conf extract:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project0

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/project0/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This _might_ be an issue with the folder permissions. Or with the http service configuration for that part of the delivered documents. You will have to add more details to your question.

Comment: A general hint: typically one puts the images folder _inside_ the base folder where the index document is.

Comment: agree with @arkascha, usually you put index.html on the outer most folder of your website.

Comment: "isn't working" has never been a good starting point for debugging things. What is the real issue? What error do you get? Please consult your browsers development console, the network tab in there, and also your http servers error log file. You need to find out what url is actually called and what the http server does on that request.

Comment: When I look at source code in Chrome, the line that 'isn't working' is as it should be (<img src="../images/P001.jpg"/> <br>). But it's a broken link. When I try to access that link (i.e. click on it), it gives me a 404 error.

Comment: I will try to put it in the same folder -was reluctant to do this, as from what I've read, you should isolate HTML from other files in the file structure, for security reasons.

Comment: You have the image folder outside the document root (as stated above) - so this is not going to work (that is the "general hint"). With it being outside the document root, a relative _client-side_ path is never going to resolve. Everything that you serve directly in the client-side HTML must be within the document root.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Can you explain to me why I am able to successfully access XML files in a separate xml/ folder (at same level as images/ folder)?

Comment: As in <?> $dom = simplexml_load_file("../xml/menu.xml"); <?> 'resolves' with no problem.

Comment: That's **server-side**, not client-side (from the browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my relative image reference isn't working.

You have the image folder outside the document root - so this is not going to work. With it being outside the document root, your relative client-side **URL** is never going to resolve (you are effectively trying to go "above" `http://example.com/`). Everything that you serve directly in the client-side HTML must be within the document root. (If you could directly access files above the DocumentRoot from the client-side browser then you would have a huge security vulnerability!)

However, your **server-side** relative **file-system path** (not a URL) resolves OK, so you can access your XML files. Note that on most shared server environments your server-side script often has access to 1 directory above the "document root". This is a good place to "hide" your server-side files, since they are not directly accessible from the browser (client-side).

Your "images" directory (which you want to access directly from your HTML) should go within the DocumentRoot eg. `/var/www/vhosts/project0/html/images`. Then you can access your images using a root-relative path (starting with a slash) from your `index.php` document in the document root, thus:

```
<img src="/images/P001.jpg">
```